# C# Listbox cant read StringBuilder.ToString()

Tags: c#, string, listbox, stringbuilder

Im trying to pass via Binding items in a row in a listbox. In my code i use StringBuilder for my variables. If i try to pass a ListBoxItem Context like this:

```
StringBuilder x;
x.Append("Something");
Name = x.ToString();
ListBox.Items.Add(x);
```

Then this will pass a null string.

But if i do this then everything is working smooth:

```
string x;
x = "Something";
Name = x;
ListBox.Items.Add(x);
```

Is there something that im missing?

Comment: Because you are adding the StringBuilder object to the List not the string you built, try `ListBox.Items.Add(x.ToString());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one has a bug:

```
StringBuilder x;
x.Append("Something");
ListBox.Items.Add(x.ToString());
```

It's being passed a string builder - not a string. Call `ToString()` on the input